# Jquery Confliting with Magento Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

I want to use Foundation 5 Reveal modal in magento product page.

I added jquery and foundation.js in footer and call Foundation from `footer.phtml`

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $(document).foundation();

</script>
```

and added modernizr and css files in `head.phtml`

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
 <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Then i added markup on product page and its working very well. But it is conflicting with magento prototype.

Then i just done `jQuery.noConflict();` and then reveal model stopped working. I thought i is becacuse i am loading two versions at same time so i removed build in jquery lib and then again prototype stopped working.

I also juggled jquery call from head to local.xml , page.xml but no luck!

**ERROR CODE: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined prototype.js:828**

Does anyone know what is the problem or mistake i am doing?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you put the `noConflict` call?

Comment: I put noconflict call in footer, head , page and local but it worked no where!

Answer (score 0):

Two things that may help:

1. It's important where you put the `noConflict` call. If the rest of your site uses PrototypeJS, then here's where I'd do it:

   ```
   <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
   <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
   <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Having done `noConflict`, you have to use `jQuery`* instead of `$` when you want to use jQuery:

   ```
   <script>

     jQuery(document).foundation();

   </script>
   ```

---

(* You don't **have** to, you can use the return value of `noConflict` to create an alias. For instance, `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` will let you use `$j` instead of `jQuery`.)

Comment: Well, I want you to know that whenever i inculde jquery prototype stopped working! So i added noconflit in head, but not worked, i put it in page not working, i put it in local but not working!

Comment: @YanHayie: If you call `noConflict` immediately after adding jQuery (as above), it **cannot** conflict with PrototypeJS. Something else is going on.

Comment: Hmm.. I see. but adding that here is the error code: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined prototype.js:828

Anything?

Comment: @YanHayie: If you have `noConflict` where I've shown above, adding jQuery will not make that happen. Can you produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think that's pretty much going to be the only way to solve this. We need information that isn't in the question, which may not be obvious to you to provide.

Comment: Well, Do you think that build in  `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` is making problem? I added jquery-2x for the foundation

Comment: @YanHayie: It doesn't matter what version, jQuery's had `noConflict` since v1.0.

Comment: maybe other plugins*?

Comment: @YanHayie: Only poorly-implemented ones. A jQuery plugin is not allowed to rely on the `$` global symbol.